# Embedding a LWC inside a partner portal/community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, partner-communities

I have set up a Partner Portal, where the users have Partner Community licenses.  I also have a LWC that has the below settings
(recently edited for clarity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Account</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" default="{!recordId}" type="String"
                label="Record ID" description="Should not be changed from default value."/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>⏎
```

As far as I know, this lightningCommunity_Page target has to be set to be able to show the LWC in the Lightning community.  Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Did you set `exposed` to `true`?

Comment: Yep

`<isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this and I edited the body to include the correct XML that works.  The fix is to specify a targetConfig along with the target as seen above.  Hopefully, someone will find this useful.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an Aura component that will host your LWC. This Aura component will act as a container for your LWC and will be used to place the LWC on your portal/community page.